# Android builds failing with compilation errors

Tags: codenameone

Im trying to build my app for android.  It is setup for notifications.  If I build with version 3.4 it gets the following error:

> /tmp/x/WordTime1/src/main/java/**com/codename1/impl/android/AndroidImplementation**.java:4576: **error: cannot find symbol
>           notification**.setLatestEventInfo(activity, contentTitle, contentBody, contentIntent);
>                       ^
>         symbol:   method 
>       setLatestEventInfo(Activity,String,String,PendingIntent)
>     location: variable notification of type Notification
>
> /tmp/x/WordTime1/src/main/java/com/codename1/impl/android/PushNotificationService.java:110: error: cannot find symbol
>               notif.setLatestEventInfo(this, value, "", contentIntent);
>                    ^
>     symbol:   method setLatestEventInfo(PushNotificationService,String,String,PendingIntent)
>     location: variable notif of type Notification

If I build with latest, it gets this error:

> /tmp/x/WordTime1/src/main/java/**com/codename1/social/GoogleImpl.java**:112: error: **cannot find symbol
>                           GoogleSignInAccount** acct = result.getSignInAccount();
>   and many more from the com/codename1/social package.

Thank you

Sam

Answer (score 0):

You should build with the latest as 3.4 is ancient by now (we are past 3.8).

The problem with the Google Signin relates to the old Google Plus login support which Google removed. You need to remove the build hints related to that and switch to the new Google Login functionality [mentioned in the developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/misc-features.html).

I mentioned the problems with the Google Connect switch [in the blog a while](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/factional-padding-margin-rounded-border-ripple-caps-google-connect.html) back.